# Do I need to apply for ESTA?

Tags: usa, esta, cancun, greek-citizens

I am Greek holding a Greek passport and travelling to Cancun directly from Amsterdam.  Do I still need to apply for ESTA?

Comment: By ESTA, do you mean the [US Electronic System for Travel Authorization (ESTA)](https://esta.cbp.dhs.gov/esta/)? And if so, are you changing planes at all in the USA?

Answer (score 4):

The only [ESTA](https://esta.cbp.dhs.gov/esta/) I know of is a system to obtain authorization to travel to the United States of America.  Your description of your itinerary doesn't mention traveling to the USA at all, so you do not need to apply for ESTA.

If your flight  involved a connection in the USA, then you would need to apply for ESTA.  But since you say you are traveling "directly" from Amsterdam, I presume that is not the case.

Answer (score 2):

[ESTA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electronic_System_for_Travel_Authorization) is a Unites States government requirement for foreign citizens.

However, if you're not visiting the USA, you have no need to get it.

So as long as your flight from Amsterdam to Cancun (or any others) don't transit, land or layover in any US airport, you do NOT need to get this, no matter what your citizenship.